# с помощью метода класса, создать экземпляр другого класса

Tags: c++

в методе fun, через if(num == 1) нужно создать экземпляр класса Bank, чтоб им можно было управлять в main. Я новичёк в программировании.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Bank {
    static int count;
    static int interest;
    double money;
    static double AllMoney;
protected:
    void Add(double num) { money += num; }
    void Get(double num) { money -= num; }
};

class Inter : public Bank {
public:
    void upper();
    void fun(int num);
};

void Inter::fun(int num) {
    if (num > 9 && num <= 0) {
        cout << "Такого пункта меню нет." << endl;
        upper();
    }
    if (num == 1) {

    }
    if (num == 2) {
        int val;

        start:
        cout << "Введите сумму: "; cin >> val;
        if (val == 0) goto start;
        else Add(val);
    }
}

void Inter::upper() {
    int number;

    cout << "Вас приветсвует программа BANK" << endl;
    cout << "           Меню" << endl;
    cout << "Создать счёт(1)" << endl;
    cout << "Пополнить счёт(2)" << endl;
    cout << "Снять деньги с счёта(3)" << endl;
    cout << "Назначить процентную ставку(4)" << endl;
    cout << "Выплатить процент(5)" << endl;
    cout << "Информация по счёту(6)" << endl;
    cout << "Обшая информация(7)" << endl;
    cout << "Выход(8)" << endl;
    cin >> number;
    fun(number);
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    Inter interface;

    while (true) {
        interface.upper();

    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы уже создаете экземпляр класса `Bank` как часть экземпляра класса `Inter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такс, Чтоб можно было "управлять" обьектом из `main` надо чтоб он там появился.
Тоесть

1) надо заменить тип с `void` на тип Bank, так как мы собираемся возвращать обьект.

2) Реализация

```
  Bank fun(int num)
    {
            if (num == 1) 
             {
               Bank bank;
                 //тт мы "заполняем" поля обьекта
                return bank;

                }
        }
```

Но и соответственно нам необходимо, чтоб в main тоже был "прием" данного возвращения.

```
int main()
 {
      int num;
      Bank catching=fun(num);
      return 0;
 }
```

Но чесно говоря, не стоит так делать, точней не правильно подобное делать, вы создадите себе кучу лишних проблем, для подобных вещей создавайте лучше отдельные функции.

Не стоит делать так чтоб функция делала "все",**разбейте  на части возможные процессы  что можно разбить**,но без фанатизма.
Вы тем самым упростите поиск проблем в своей программе. И сделаете её понятней.